# How to add custom attribute in new order confirmation email in Magento 1.9.3?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, email, order-email

I have created custom attribute for product code. I want to add this product code in new order confirmation email. How can I implement this?

[image]

I have assigned these product codes to different products. When customer place order of these products, product code should show in new order confirmation email.

> app/design/frontend/rwd/mytheme/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml

I am trying to edit code in this file but I do not know where to add code to show my custom attribute in order email template

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem() ?>
<?php $_order = $this->getItem()->getOrder() ?>


<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="cell-content product-info">
        <p class="product-name"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></p>
       <p class="sku"><?php echo $this->__('SKU'); ?>: 
        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getSku($_item)) ?></p>



        <?php if ($this->getItemOptions()): ?>
            <dl style="margin:0; padding:0;">

        <?php foreach ($this->getItemOptions() as $option): ?>
                        <dt><strong><em><?php echo $option['label'] ?></em></strong></dt>
                        <dd style="margin:0; padding:0 0 0 9px;">
                            <?php echo nl2br($option['value']) ?>
                            </dd>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </dl>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $addInfoBlock = $this->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
            <?php if ($addInfoBlock) :?>
                <?php echo $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
        </td>
        <td class="cell-content align-center"><?php echo $_item->getQtyOrdered()*1 ?></td>
        <td class="cell-content align-right">
            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displaySalesPriceExclTax($_order->getStore()) || $this->helper('tax')->displaySalesBothPrices($_order->getStore())): ?>
                <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displaySalesBothPrices($_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <span class="label"><?php echo Mage::helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax'); ?>:</span>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()); ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>


                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>
                    <br />
                    <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                        <small>
                            <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                                <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </small>
                    <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="nobr"><small><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'],true,true); ?></small></span><br />
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                        <small>
                            <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                                <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </small>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                        <br />
                        <span class="nobr"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total'); ?>:<br /> <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()); ?></span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>


            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displaySalesPriceInclTax($_order->getStore()) || $this->helper('tax')->displaySalesBothPrices($_order->getStore())): ?>
                <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displaySalesBothPrices($_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <br /><span class="label"><?php echo Mage::helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax'); ?>:</span>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php $_incl = $this->helper('checkout')->getSubtotalInclTax($_item); ?>
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_incl + Mage::helper('weee')->getRowWeeeTaxInclTax($_item)); ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_incl-$_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>
                    <br />
                    <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                        <small>
                            <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                                <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </small>
                    <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="nobr"><small><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></small></span><br />
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                        <small>
                            <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                                <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </small>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total incl. tax'); ?>:<br /> <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_incl + Mage::helper('weee')->getRowWeeeTaxInclTax($_item)); ?></span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php if ($_item->getGiftMessageId() && $_giftMessage = $this->helper('giftmessage/message')->getGiftMessage($_item->getGiftMessageId())): ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" style=" border-bottom:2px solid #CCCCCC; padding:3px 9px;">
            <strong style="color:#444444; font-size:11px;"><?php echo $this->__('Gift Message') ?></strong>
            <?php echo $this->__('From:'); ?> <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?><br />
            <?php echo $this->__('To:'); ?> <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?><br />
            <strong><?php echo $this->__('Message:'); ?></strong><br /><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getMessage()) ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: can You Please specify more detail of your custom attribute @Aks

Comment: Maybe this is usefull: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258004/add-custom-attribute-variable-to-order-confirmation-e-mail-template

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite `queueNewOrderEmail()`from `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` to your **local** codepool then you add your attribute to get it in the template dynamically.

Line: 1339:

```
// Set all required params and send emails
        $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId));
        $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
        $mailer->setTemplateId($templateId);
        $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
            'order'        => $this,
            'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
            'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml  // don't forget to add => , <= here in the end
            'your_attribute_here' => ...
        ));
```

Then you retrieve the attribute in your template in : `app/locale/langue_ISO/template/email/sales/order_new.html`